# Blaze.getData(el) returns null unless data property is accessed

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to make a list of re-orderable items in Meteor.  My items have a `info.order` property which I change on click events.  Why does the example below work until I comment out if the line below `// ! ...`?

If I comment out that line I get the error `Cannot read property '_id' of null` when `data._id` is referenced in the event handler.

This is minimal Meteor javascript:

```
Widget = new Mongo.Collection('widget');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    function moveUp (mongo_id) {
        var clicked = Widget.findOne({_id: mongo_id});
        var above = Widget.findOne({'info.order': clicked.info.order - 1});
        if (above) {
            Widget.update({_id: clicked._id}, {$inc: {"info.order": -1}});
            Widget.update({_id: above._id}, {$inc: {"info.order": 1}});
        }
    }

    Template.widget.helpers({
        // Get list of widget to display and sort by latest first.
        widget: function(data){
            return  Widget.find({}, {sort: {'info.order': 1}});
        },

        display: function(mongo_id, info) {
            var html = '<div>';
            html += '<div>' + info.label + '</div>';
            html += '<div><a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-moveup">Up</a></div>';

            // ! IF NEXT LINE IS COMMENTED-OUT data == null IN EVENT HANDLER
            html += '<div>' + info.order + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
        return html;
        }

    });

    Template.widget.events({
    'click .js-moveup': function(e, tpl){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = Blaze.getData(e.currentTarget);
            moveUp(data._id);
    }
    });
} // end is MeteorClient
```

With this template:

```
<head></head>
<body>
  {{> widget}}
</body>

<template name="widget">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Widgets</h1>
    {{#each widget}}
    {{{display _id info}}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And this seed data:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Widget.find().count() === 0) {
        [{info :{label: "first", order: 1}},
         {info: {label: "second", order: 2}},
         {info: {label: "third", order: 3}}
        ].forEach(function(w){
    Widget.insert(w);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: When the line is commented out, the click event works the first time (two of the items swap places) but subsequent clicks give the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea what's going on...

Meteor must compare the output of `display()` to it's previous value and only evaluate update the DOM if it has changed (or something similar). If I don't print out info.order the HTML of each widget is unchanged.

I tested this by replacing `info.order` with `new Date()` to add varying content that didn't reference the model and, sure enough, the widgets more as expected.

So, my take home message is that if you return raw HTML from display Meteor will try to do the write thing but won't always get it right.